# Create columns in an excel file using a variable

Tags: excel, templates, variables, insert, crosstab

**Background:**

I am exporting a crosstab query from access to the excel template. Since its a crosstab query, when i select different dates to see the productivity report, it gives me different records with different header names each time i run it ( Which are all clients name ). Which means the headers are not consistent. Sometime i get 1 column with a header and sometime i get 5 columns of records with the header.

**Question:** As i mentioned earlier, i am exporting to an **excel template** which has Total fields all the way to the right side of the excel sheet and in the bottom of each column. I do not want my query header to over lap with the calculated fields to the right. I just want the query records and headers to append left side of the total fields so once the record gets inserted in the excel file they will be automatically calculated. How can I do this.

**P.S:** My query is being exported successfully but as of now its overlapping with the total fields to the right. Also in my VBA coding its giving me the count of columns about to append in the excel. Just thought i should let you guys know.
Thanks